# Update statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
function add_new($father,$chName)  // add new category
{

    if($father = "1" ) {


$result = mysql_query("INSERT into stinky_menu (title,nest_under)
        VALUES('".$chName."','1')");

    } 
     else { 

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE stinky_menu SET title  = '$chName' nest_under = '$father'");

     }

 }
```

I am getting the value of father from parent page, but its not going to else condition if its not equal to one.

Comment: Didn't forget your where clause in the update statement?

Answer (score 4):

You’re using the [assignment operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) `=` rather than the [comparison operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `==`. So try this:

```
if ($father == "1") {
    // …
} else {
    // …
}
```

Comment: One way to avoid that kind of typo/error is to "reverse" the condition, like this : 

if ('1' == $father) {...}

This way, if you put only one '=', you'll get a Parse error, and immediatly notice the problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you have

```
if($father = "1")
```

You need to use "==".  "=" is the assignment operator.  You are setting $father equal to "1" even when it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if ($father == 1){}
```

Read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) about comparison operators. "=" is the assignment operator.

Look at this to see what your code does:

```
<?php
    $father = 55;

    if ($father = 1){}
    else{}

    echo $father;
?>
```

This prints "1".

Answer (score 0):

Also, should not that last query be:

```
"UPDATE stinky_menu SET title  = '$chName', nest_under = '$father'"
```